# Armazenar Arquivos

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma dúvida quanto ao upload de arquivos, tenho que criar pastas para cada cliente e guardar arquivos deles (arquivos word, Excel, txt, dwg, dxf, ascii, pdf) ?

Seria viável armazenar isso tudo para cada cliente em um diretório online ou teria a possibilidade de salvar em um pc no escritório e usar as pastas armazenadas nesse pc para serem acessado em outros pcs com sistema online?

Isso está me tirando o sono.

Comment: Pelo que entendi você precisa criar pastas para cada tipo de arquivo, não é mesmo?

Comment: seria uma pasta: NomeCliente que terá os arquivos upados podendo ser de qualquer uma ou de todas as extensões mencionadas... meu medo é minha hospedagem ficar com acesso muito lento

Comment: Olhe se [este artigo](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308150/pt-br) pode lhe ajudar,

Comment: se eu armazenasse esses arquivos no bd seria uma boa?? ou no diretorio seria melhor????

Comment: Imagino que no bd.

Comment: Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: vou consultar com o pessoal da empresa, seu eu soubesse C# isso seria facil de resolver....   daqui pro final do ano eu aprendo isso... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viável mesmo e mais estável, é fazer o upload disso no servidor mesmo (online).

### Servidor / Online

Claro, que de uma forma organizada. Por exemplo:

```
/diretorio_de_upload/clientes/id-do-cliente/tipo-do-arquivo/arquivo.ext
```

Assim, ao menos tudo fica organizado por **cliente e tipo de arquivo**.

### Computador do Escritório

Pra fazer isso, você vai ter que configurar **muito mais coisas**, por exemplo:

- Configurar o roteador para permitir conexões
- Configurar o redirecionamento da conexão baseado na porta
- Configurar as permissões do acesso (chato / perigoso)
- Manter ele sempre ligado
- E se desejar complicar um pouco mais, configurar um DNS nele e permitir que ele seja acessado diretamente através de um host/dominio: *entre aspas, você está configurando um servidor no escritório*

### Resumindo

O mais prático, simples e rápido sem dúvida é manter online.

### Custo x Benefício

Talvez por conta da quantidade de arquivos / acesso seja melhor você pegar algum servidor que te provê isso **sob demanda**.

Aconselho ler/estudar/verificar os servidores Amazon (AWS): http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Comment: Gostei dessa ideia do Amazon (AWS)

Comment: @henrique Se a resposta te ajudou e foi a resposta correta para sua pergunta, não esqueça de marcá-la.